# filterProperty in Emberjs with a property from a binding

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript

I am working in emberjs and I am trying to use filterProperty so that I would be able to call `{{#each messageFromGroup}}` in handlebars. However, the following code does not work when getting trying to filter based on `group.id`. However (for example) in the current context (in the function messageFromGroup) `console.log @get 'group.id` will return a number (2 for example). The code:

```
App.MessagesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend

  group: null

  needs: 'group'

  groupBinding: "controllers.group"



  messageFromGroup: (->

      return @get('model').filterProperty 'to', @get('group.id')

  ).property 'model.@each.to'
```

Note: if I write the code as follows it works and this leads me to believe that something with looking up `@get group.id` is the problem.

```
App.MessagesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend

  group: null

  needs: 'group'

  groupBinding: "controllers.group"



  messageFromGroup: (->

      return @get('model').filterProperty 'to', 2

  ).property 'model.@each.to'
```

Comment: Maybe the value from `group.id` is initally null, and after is updated, but the computed property isn't aware of this. Try to use property('model.@each.to', 'group.id'), in `messageFromGroup`

Comment: I just tried that, it still doesn't work. I don't fully understand the behavior of the bindings, but I am somewhat sure (not very) that since console.log @get 'group.id' works in that context that the value is not null. However messing around with property may be the key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the `groupBinding` is there to facilitate the access to the `GroupController`? I do not know, why this does not work, but i would not use a binding in this case. I would use an alias. Therefore plz try this:

```
App.MessagesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
   ...
   group : Ember.computed.alias("controllers.group")
});
```

**Edit:** I just saw that this cannot be an issue, since you say that a logstatement for group.id is working properly. Then the only other issue could be that `@get('group.id')` is returning a String but you need a number.

Comment: Yes :) It was returning a string for some reason. Just had to force it to an int. Very strange considering the value is originally an int. Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: Difficult to guess i think, one would have to see the data flow and check when group.id is set and what happens from now on. Maybe you could use an observer on group.id to check what happens there :-)